# Unable to get the expected legend shown in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm creating a horizontal merging bars using chart js. Here I'm able to get the output correctly, but the problem is, for legend labels, I'm able to show only 1. and here is my output.

[image]

In the top of the chart, we can see SFO and CHI legend(this is a workaround or may be my luck, but this is not exactly I am looking for). Similar to AMER, We've APAC and it also has 2 colors, green and light green, green shows India and light Green shows ANZ, Can I get the legends as shown for AMER, Also can please suggest me a better way of getting this.

Here is my data.

```
var MeSeData = {
  labels: [
    "AMER",
    "APAC",
   "EMEA"
  ],
  datasets: [{
      label: ['SFO'],
      data: [23.2, 28.2, 6.1],
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange']
    },
    {
      label: ['CHI'],
      data: [6.3, 3],
      backgroundColor: ['lightred', 'lightgreen']
    }
  ]
};
```

Here is my current working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ozrpgw3/1/)

I'm using chart.js. please let me know on how Can I achieve this requirement.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation to understand how the data is populated.

All the properties in `labels` corresponds to what is to be shown in the xAxis in your case it is inverted.

The number of items in the datasets corresponds to the legend and the `label` property of each `dataset` is used as the text for the legend.

Please see the changes code as per my understanding of your problem or fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/bcxzu39v/

```
var MeSeContext = document.getElementById("MeSeStatusCanvas").getContext("2d");
var MeSeData = {
  labels: [
    "AMER",
    "APAC",
    "EMEA"
  ],
  datasets: [{
      label: ['SFO'],
      data: [23.2, 0, 0],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    {
      label: ['CHI'],
      data: [6.3, 0],
      backgroundColor: 'brown'
    },
    {
      label: ['INDIA'],
      data: [0, 3, 0],
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    {
      label: ['ANZ'],
      data: [0, 7, 0],
      backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
    }
  ]
};

var MeSeChart = new Chart(MeSeContext, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: MeSeData,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,

      }]
    }
  }
});
```